# Not able to place image between buttons

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to create the template shown below in android code, can anyone help me do this,

[image]

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Username"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:password="true"
        android:hint="Password"/>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="70dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/blue">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
                    android:text="Login In"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@color/blue"/>
                 <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Sign Up"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:background="@color/blue"/>
            </LinearLayout>
           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="50dp"
               android:layout_height="50dp"
               android:gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
           </LinearLayout>
       </RelativeLayout>
```

Above is the code I have written to achieve this but looks like I am doing it wrong, Can anyone help me understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` in your linearLayout

```
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
       </LinearLayout>
```